# Split date range (timestamp) into equal parts by Month- SQL Server

Tags: date, split

Experts,
Have a question regarding splitting a date range into equal parts by months including the time part

example - fromdate - 06/29/2020 09:00:00 and todate - 06/29/2021 09:00:00

Want to split this date range into twelve equal parts like below

```
06/29/2020 09:00:00 - 06/30/2020 12:59:59
07/01/2020 00:00:00 - 07/31/2020 12:59:59
.........
.......
06/01/2021 00:00:00 - 06/29/2021 09:00:00
```

I cant write recursive CTE as this is a sql synapse module I am running against..

With below query I am able to split the date part, but time part is not coming properly as above.. Please help me as this is a blocking my development

```
declare @FromTs DATETIME
declare @ToTs DATETIME
SET @FromTs = GetDate()
SET @ToTs = DATEADD(month, 12, @FromTs)

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.all_columns
),
d(qi,qrt,qtt,n,f,t,md,bp,ep,rn) AS  
(
    SELECT 
    ,n.n, @FromTs, @ToTs, 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromTs, @ToTs),
    DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY( @FromTs),  @FromTs)),
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, 
    DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY( @FromTs),  @FromTs))))
    FROM n INNER JOIN <datetbl> AS d 
    ON @ToTs >= DATEADD(MONTH, n.n-1, @FromTs)
)
SELECT qi,qrt,qtt,
new_from_date = CASE n WHEN 0  THEN f ELSE bp END,
new_to_date   = CASE n WHEN md THEN t ELSE ep END,rn
FROM d WHERE md >= n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
-- Range borders
src_data AS (SELECT CAST('2020-06-29 09:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS fromdate, 
                    CAST('2021-06-29 09:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS todate),
-- numbers table
numbers AS (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
             UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
             UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11)                         
-- The query
SELECT num + 1 id, 
       DATEADD(SECOND, num * DATEDIFF(SECOND, fromdate, todate) / 12, fromdate) fromdate,
       DATEADD(SECOND, (num + 1) * DATEDIFF(SECOND, fromdate, todate) / 12, fromdate) todate
FROM src_data, numbers
ORDER BY id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=446f459e292e0086a5df89a16b8d5eab)

The range is divided to equal (in seconds) parts. You may alter the calculations granularity (for example, use `HOURS` instead of `SECOND`), parts lengths will be adjusted and rounded automatically.

You may replace `numbers` CTE with any other which gets/generates the integers list from `0` to `parts_amount-1`, and parametrize the divident used in a query (`12`, may be replaced with, for example, `SELECT COUNT(num) FROM numbers`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.. Only one issue now is that the time part is overlapping like below2020-06-29 20:31:33.873 2020-07-30 06:31:33.873
2020-07-30 06:31:33.873 2020-08-29 16:31:33.873
2020-08-29 16:31:33.873 2020-09-29 02:31:33.873

Comment: @Tech_Enthu *the time part is overlapping* I think this is impossible. Adjacent, that is true - but this is how it should be. Edit source data in the fiddle, post the link and point on the rows pair with overlapping.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8dac7eaa5db36a15f156d9ee11d36dca

Comment: if you see above fiddle link, the new_to_date and new_from_date is same from second row onwards

Comment: I see that `new_to_date` in each row is equal to `new_from_date` in the next row. This is normal. Maybe you need to round datetime values to days? do it additionally...